# startSearch does not start search activity

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview, searchactivity

I added a SearchView in my activity and defined a search activity to handle the search. I added the OnQueryTextListener and called `startSearch()` method from `onQueryTextSubmit()` method. When I set global search as `true`, it launches google search. When I set it to `false`, nothing happens. Below is the code:

```
final SearchView searchText = (SearchView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
     searchText.setFocusable(true);
     searchText.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
     searchText.setQueryHint(SearchActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.search_text_hint));
     final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             // Do something
             final String searchText = newText;
             if (newText.equals("")) {
                 suggestAdapter.removeAll();
                 suggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 return true;
             }
             if (newText.length() < 4) {
                 return true;
             }
             if (!last_onTextChanged.equals(newText))
                 onchangeHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
             else
                 return true;
             last_onTextChanged = newText;
             onchangeHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     getSearchSuggestions(searchText);
                 }
             },800);
             return true;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
             // Do something
             startSearch(query,true,null,false);
             return true;
         }
     };
     searchText.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

The following is defined in custom Action Bar layout **custom_search_action_bar.xml**

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/logo_green"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/ic_abc_button"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="@color/logo_green"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/ic_barcode_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The following is defined in **res/xml/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</searchable>
```

And finally in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.activity.tabsearch.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
        android:parentActivityName=".view.activity.tabsearch.SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.rayat.pricewiz.view.activity.tabsearch.SearchActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
    <provider android:name="com.rayat.pricewiz.provider.SearchContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.rayat.pricewiz.provider.SearchContentProvider" />
</application>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No, I ended up adding my own implementation of manually adding the Edittext and button in action bar and handling the search query. Override the `handleIntent` method of the activity to prevent the search results activity opening another activity instance of itself

Comment: Yep, same thing here, I did that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put this for your MainActivity in the Manifest.xml

```html
        <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>
```